# Do Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 have the same hash code for a string?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to use `String.hash` to generate the hash code, but I'm worried that if some time later I upgrade the version from 1.8 to 1.9, the hash code generated will also change.

Do Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 have the same hash code for a string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fortunately, the answer is easy because they do not:

```
~$ ruby1.8 -e 'p "hello world".hash'
444332266
~$ ruby1.9 -e 'p "hello world".hash'
-194819219
```

If you use the builtin hash method, I would recommend having a script as part of your build process that generates the necessary hashcodes. Note that they are not guaranteed to be the same even from one machine to the next.

If you need consistent hashing, use something like [CRC32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):

```
>> require 'zlib'
>> Zlib.crc32 "hello world"
=> 222957957
>> require 'digest'
>> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "hello world"
=> "2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed"
>> Digest::MD5.hexdigest "hello world"
=> "5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3"
```

They have quite different purposes, but CRC32 has the advantage of returning a 32-bit number and being quite fast, while SHA1 is an 80-bit number but more secure. (I’m assuming this is not for cryptographic purposes, but look into SHA-256 if you need it.)

Comment: thank you very much, now i can decide that the ruby hash function is not reliable. i should choose myself hash function to generate the code like ruby hash code. do you have some suggestion? :-) i added one further question?

Comment: but which function should i use? MD5 SHA or others? thank you a lot.

Comment: @ywenbo I have answered that as well.

Comment: The Ruby `#hash` method is entirely reliable for its intended use: getting hash values of objects so that they can be used internally by Ruby to populate in-memory data structures such as instances of `Hash`.