# Rails creating schema_migrations - Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am using Rails 3.2.6 and Mysql 6.0.9 (but I have exactly the same error on MySQL 5.2.25)

When I create new database (`rake db:create`) and then when I try to load the schema (`rake schema:load`) I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `unique_schema_migrations` ON `schema_migrations` (`version`)
```

After hours and hours of research I found these solutions:

### 1. Change MySQL variable innodb_large_prefix to true (or ON)

This didn't work. I tried it on my Linux server, my Mac and even on Windows - it just doesn't work.

### 2. Monkeypatch ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.create_table

I do not need the `version` column to be 255 long (when it is UTF-8, then it takes 4*255 = 1020 bytes and exceeds the MySQL limit of 767 byte for keys). I do not need it to be UTF-8 either, but all other tables in the DB are UTF-8 and I have set utf8_czech_ci to be the default collation.

The method that actually creates the schema_migrations table looks like this:

```
def self.create_table
  unless connection.table_exists?(table_name)
    connection.create_table(table_name, :id => false) do |t|
      t.column :version, :string, :null => false
    end
    connection.add_index table_name, :version, :unique => true, :name => index_name
  end
end
```

You can read the whole file on [Github rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb)

So I tried to add `:limit => 100` to the `t.column` statement, but I did not succeed with this solution either. The problem is that I cannot make this patch load when the originial is already in place. In other words - my patch loads *before* ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration so it is overwritten.

When I put this in `config/initializers/patches/schema_migration.rb`:

```
require 'active_record/scoping/default'
require 'active_record/scoping/named'
require 'active_record/base'

module ActiveRecord
  class SchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.create_table
      unless connection.table_exists?(table_name)
        connection.create_table(table_name, :id => false) do |t|
          t.column :version, :string, :null => false, :limit => 100
        end
        connection.add_index table_name, :version, :unique => true, :name => index_name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is successfully loaded, but the it is overwritten when the original ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration is loaded.

I tried to mess up with ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) but that doesn't seem to work either.

**Is there a way to load this file after the originial ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration is in place and make this patch work?**

Do you have any suggestions? I can clarify any part of this question, if it makes no sense to you. Just ask me. I've been stuck with this for too long.

Comment: Have you considered creating `schema_migrations` (complete with a sensible column size) by hand before doing any Rails stuff at all?

Comment: Yes I have considered that, but I am afraid that this will not work with `rake db:test:clone`? Also, It will complicate setup on production servers/developer machines, because I will have to run some script to pre-initialize the db and create this table.

Answer (score 9):

767 key should work. Make sure you use `utf8` encoding, and not `utf16`. 
I had same problem, and my mistake was that I accidently created `utf16` database

Comment: Add>> "encoding: utf8" in database.yml

Comment: This error is caused by using `utf8mb4` encoding for database which was made specifically for allowing emoji and other utf8 characters. What you are offering is going back to `utf8` with no support for extended unicode.

Comment: You can limit your indexed column to 191 or less using utf8mb4. THe problem happens because in uft8mb4 maxlength is in bytes.

Comment: Worked! +1 And `collation` is is set to `utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to drop your database and recreate a new one with the following instructions :

```
 mysql -u root -p -e "CREATE DATABASE {DB_NAME} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a column named version for varchar of length 2000

```
class AddVersionToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :version, :string, limit:2000
    add_index  :users, :version
  end
end
```

I was using this latin 1 1 character 1 byte, but now I want to use  utf8mb4 1 character 4 bytes.

Configuring your databse like this you can get index until 3072 bytes:

```
docker run -p 3309:3306 --name test-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Cal1mero. -d mariadb:10.2 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --innodb-large-prefix=1 --innodb-file-format=barracuda --innodb-file-per-table=1 --innodb-strict-mode=1 --innodb-default-row-format=dynamic
```

this is enough for latin_1, (will be 2000 bytes), but for utf8mb4 it will be 8000 bytes. In this keys you have some options

Add a column named hash_version and implement the index on that column.

[Consistent String#hash based only on the string's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536885/consistent-stringhash-based-only-on-the-strings-content)

Make the string shorter, it should work , but depernds on your needs

or use fulltext in your migrations, like this:

```
class AddVersionToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :version, :string, limit:2000
    add_index  :users, :version, type: :fulltext
  end
end
```

references:

- https://mensfeld.pl/2016/06/ruby-on-rails-mysql2error-incorrect-string-value-and-specified-key-was-too-long/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/innodb-restrictions.html
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35821/possible-index-on-a-varchar-field-in-mysql