# Ruby- Mysql2 encoding utf8mb4 creating problems for indexing(hence affecting performance)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, encoding

I am trying to create a composite index on my table because the below table is giving me performance issues and it has a character encoding of ut8mb4 and I am getting the following error

```
Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long
```

The entire error is given below:-

```
== 20161103114941 AddIndexOnKeyAndIdOnInvitees: migrating - Shard: master =====
-- add_index(:invitees, [:key, :created_at])
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX `index_invitees_on_key_and_created_at`  ON `invitees` (`key`, `created_at`) 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `query'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/abstract_adapter.rb:15:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:529:in `add_index'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/var/www/production_hobnob_copy/db/migrate/20161103114941_add_index_on_key_and_id_on_invitees.rb:3:in `change'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1043:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/migration.rb:86:in `migrate_with_octopus'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/migration.rb:113:in `block in up_with_octopus'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:509:in `using_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:245:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:492:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:244:in `run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:253:in `block in send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/migration.rb:112:in `up_with_octopus'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/migration.rb:104:in `block in migrate_with_octopus'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:509:in `using_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:245:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:492:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:244:in `run_queries_on_shard'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:253:in `block in send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:252:in `send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ar-octopus-0.8.6/lib/octopus/migration.rb:103:in `migrate_with_octopus'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I went through the following post in this forum:-

[Rails creating schema_migrations - Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644804/rails-creating-schema-migrations-mysql2error-specified-key-was-too-long)

and the solution given is to convert the character encoding to utf8 which is not possible in my case. Is there a work around for this.

Any suggestions or help will be very helpful..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions, indexes were limited to 767 bytes.  This was enough room for `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8`, which was popular.

`VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` needs more than that.  Newer versions have raised the limit, so it will work.

Solutions:

- Upgrade mysql.
- Decrease 255 -- Look at your data and use a sensible number, not the overworked 255.  If that is less than 191, your indexes will work.
- Get 5.6.3 / 5.5.14 (or later) and...

Instructions (not needed for 5.7.7 and later)

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Then maybe you can index (255) utf8mb4.

"key too long" only indirectly impacts "performance" in that you can't add the index.

Comment: I understand but because I can't index the query it's taking a long time to execute..I will try what you said and get back..thanks for the answer

Comment: MySql version we are using is 5.6 and we cant decrease 255. Can you please provide the workaround?

Comment: You have strings longer than 191?  Or you can't do `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Added the instructions.