# Why do String hashes change?

Tags: ruby, hashcode

I have this code:

```
class DocumentIdentifier
  attr_reader :folder, :name

  def initialize( folder, name )
    @folder = folder
    @name = name
  end

  def ==(other)
    return true if other.equal?(self)
    return false unless other.kind_of?(self.class)
    folder == other.folder && name == other.name
  end

  def hash
    folder.hash ^ name.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    return false unless other.instance_of?(self.class)
    other.folder == folder && other.name == name
  end
end

first_id = DocumentIdentifier.new('secret/plans', 'raygun.txt')
puts first_id.hash
```

Why is the hash code changing for each call?

I think it should remain the same as a String hash code in Java. Or, the hashcode is changing because every call gives me new instances of `folder` and `name`? Ruby's String type has an implementation of the hash method, so the same String should give me the same number for each call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same string doesn't return same hash between two sessions of Ruby, only in the current session.

```
➜  tmp  pry
[1] pry(main)> "foo".hash
=> -3172192351909719463
[2] pry(main)> exit
➜  tmp  pry
[1] pry(main)> "foo".hash
=> 2138900251898429379
[2] pry(main)> "foo".hash
=> 2138900251898429379
```

Comment: Was on my way to say the same thing. I'd recommend the poster use `Digest::SHA1` or an equivalent instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452161/do-ruby-1-8-and-1-9-have-the-same-hash-code-for-a-string for some related info.

Comment: Thank you for posting, automatically goes to my favorites questions

Comment: It's a security feature. If the hash would be predictable, a malevolent user could precompute lots of strings with the same hash and feed them to your app, hampering performance.

Comment: +1 @steenslag. That was an exploit seen against Hash types in other other languages for the same reason.

Comment: Ok I confused. How will Hash object figured out in which bucked has to find a key (suppose we  use key which will be an object with implemented hash and eql? methods), when key is changing between each call. I suppose that Ruby doesn't function as Java, which load object into jvm, but create instances which only live during script execution.

Comment: @bodo: Not between each +call+, it changes between each +session+. All hashes do that in Ruby 1.9, BTW, not just string